# Ctrl+Shift works only on opposing sides on external keyboard

Tags: windows-10, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an external keyboard (Logitech K120, Windows Layout) connected to my notebook, running Windows 10, and since today I am facing problems when using shortcuts that involve Ctrl+Shift.

One concrete use-case that I have and struggle with is selecting whole words per short-cut, i.e. "Ctrl+Shift+Left or Right Arrow". On the built-in keyboard that works, on the external only with Ctrl+Shift on opposing ends of the keyboard.

Specifically, if I want to use them **I have to use the keys on opposing sides of the keyboard**.

The following **do work**, but in my opinion make for a very awkward hand-positioning:

- "Left-Side Ctrl + Right-Side Shift + Arrow key"
- "Right-Side Ctrl + Left-Side Shift + Arrow key"

The following combinations **don't work**:

- "Left-Side Ctrl + Left-Side Shift + Arrow key"
- "Right-Side Ctrl + Right-Side Shift + Arrow key"

I checked the following scenarios which all worked fine:

- Try the shortcuts on the built-in keyboard of the notebook
- Try the keyboard on another computer
- Try another keyboard on the notebook

Therefore I assume, that it is a driver issue. But uninstalling the keyboard via the device manager did not work.

The problem coincides with two things: On the notebook an update of the MS Office Suite to Office 365 took place and the keyboard was attached to a Mac.
I somehow doubt, that this actually has to do anything with each other, but maybe it is useful information.

I would be really glad for any kind of information how this problem could be solved.
Thank you.

Comment: looks like [keyboard ghosting/key rollover issue](https://superuser.com/q/1392966/241386)

Comment: [What is the expected behavior when holding down two keys on a keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/1597657/241386)

Comment: Hello @phuclv thank you for your reply. But I don't think this is the issue here. Maybe I didn't make it clear enough in the text, but the shortcuts in general do work but not if I use the Ctrl and Shift keys, that are located on the same end of the keyboard. If I use the opposing keys, i.e. "Right-side Ctrl + Left-side Shift" it works fine. I will add this clarification to my question.

Comment: yes that's exactly the behavior of key rollovers. Because keys close together use the same line in the matrix, causing the inability to differentiate them. Although rolling over 2 common keys like Ctrl and Shift is weird

Comment: @phuclv But the thing is, it was working with this exact same keyboard previously and is still working if I attach it to another computer. This wikipedia article in the one post suggests to me, that the rollover is a hardware issue, so my problem should occur regardless of where I plug it to.

Comment: I have one more remark to make which I will also put in the original post: I forgot to mention that I'm using a kvm-switch to attach the keyboard to my computer - also previously have, when it was still working. If I attach the keyboard now directly to the computer it actually works fine. Only when keeping it in the switch it does not. Also not, if I attach the switch to the same plug where the keyboard would work.

Comment: I solved it. Somehow only one of those input-plugs of the switch works anymore properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem myself and maybe the solution (though, nobody could have given it to me here, because I didn't realize nor mentioned that this actually changed) will help somebody, that will stumble over the same issue.

The keyboard is attached to the computer via a kvm-switch that has 4 USB-sockets, two of which are marked USB-2.0 and the other two as K/M for **k**eyboard and **m**ouse (I don't know what this means in terms of a USB version, probably something older).

Apparently, earlier the keyboard was attached to one of the USB-2.0 sockets but then I mixed it up and attached it to the K/M-sockets but they seem to have caused the problem.

After attaching the keyboard back to the USB-2.0 socket everything works fine now.

Comment: It's possible these K/M allow the switch to act as constantly connected keyboard+mouse for each computer. A device connected to a general-purpose USB vanishes from one computer when it gets attached to another. For a keyboard or a mouse this may be problematic in some circumstances (e.g. "no keyboard detected" error at boot). Therefore the switch can pretend to be a keyboard and a mouse all the time for all computers, but only relay events from actual keyboard and mouse to the chosen computer. I guess in your case the issue was in this layer. Connecting to a general-purpose USB bypasses this.

Comment: Compare to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/781631/432690).